# Is there a OSQA for python 3?

Tags: django

Our team decides to move to python 3, and `BitNami OSQA Stack 1.0rc-3` is no longer supported. I've been looking it up all day but no results. I think maybe it is very easy for someone to find it, so I came here for help.

In short: something like *BitNami OSQA Stack 1.0rc-3*, which implemented with python 3.

Or,something has the following features:

1.implemented with python 3 and Django

2.Open Source Q&A System

and better (optional)

3.Simplfied-Chinese version

thanks in advance.

Comment: Not sure whether askbot runs on python 3. I don't think so, but maybe recent development might have changed that. https://github.com/ASKBOT